# Fetch all records before a particular event in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this `DATA`

```
+--------+--------+----------+------+
| TranID | CustID | TransSeq | Type |
+--------+--------+----------+------+
|    1   |  100   |      1   | A    |
|    2   |  100   |      2   | A    |
|    3   |  100   |      3   | B    |
|    4   |  200   |      1   | A    |
|    5   |  200   |      2   | B    |
|    6   |  200   |      3   | A    |
|    7   |  200   |      4   | A    |
|    8   |  200   |      5   | A    |
+--------+--------+----------+------+
```

I want to fetch all records before `Type B`. Hence my output will be like this

```
+--------+--------+----------+------+
| TranID | CustID | TransSeq | Type |
+--------+--------+----------+------+
|    1   |  100   |      1   | A    |
|    2   |  100   |      2   | A    |
|    4   |  200   |      1   | A    |
+--------+--------+----------+------+
```

One way that I can think of is the following

**Step 1 - Create temp table storing CustID and TransSeq where type == B**

```
CREATE TABLE TEMP AS
select CustID, TransSeq as TransSeq_B from DATA 
where Type = "B"
```

The output of step 1 looks like this

```
+--------+------------+------+
| CustID | TransSeq_B | Type |
+--------+------------+------+
|  100   |      3     | B    |
|  200   |      2     | B    |
+--------+------------+------+
```

**Step 2 - Merge TEMP with DATA using CustID**

```
CREATE TABLE DATA_NEW AS
select D.TranID, D.CustID, D.TransSeq, D.Type, T.TransSeq_B
from DATA inner join TEMP on D.CustID = T.CustID
```

The output of step 2 looks like this

```
+--------+--------+----------+------+------------+
| TranID | CustID | TransSeq | Type | TransSeq_B |
+--------+--------+----------+------+------------+
|    1   |  100   |      1   | A    |       3    |
|    2   |  100   |      2   | A    |       3    |
|    3   |  100   |      3   | B    |       3    |
|    4   |  200   |      1   | A    |       2    |
|    5   |  200   |      2   | B    |       2    |
|    6   |  200   |      3   | A    |       2    |
|    7   |  200   |      4   | A    |       2    |
|    8   |  200   |      5   | A    |       2    |
+--------+--------+----------+------+------------+
```

**Step 3 - Query this new table from step 2 and keep records where all TransSeq is less than TransSeq_B**

```
select * from DATA_NEW
where TransSeq < TransSeq_B
```

Is there any efficient way of doing this, as I have many records (>20M)

Comment: There are an A and a B with transseq = 2. Why is that A in the expected results?

Comment: It looks like you just need to find the last `TranID` where type = 'B' and get all the rows above it. because, in your example, you are getting all the rows above `TranID = 5`

Comment: @GolezTrol - for custID 100, transeq 1, 2 is A and 3 is B. Hence they both occurred before B and is the output expected

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya - yes you are right

Comment: What EXACTLY do you mean when you say 'before'? The rows of an SQL table don't have a natural order. So what is the order of the entries in your table? Is it just ordered by the `TranID` or do the `TransSeq` and `TransSeq_B` columns matter in this question?

Comment: Ah, per customer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically got the idea quite right - the only thing you need to do is instead of creating new tables, use the relevant queries as Views into a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT
  beforeB.*
FROM
  Table1 AS beforeB
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
      CustID,
      MIN(TransSeq) AS TransSeq
    FROM Table1
    WHERE Type='B'
    GROUP BY CustID
  ) AS theB
  ON beforeB.CustID=theB.CustID
WHERE
  beforeB.TransSeq<theB.TransSeq
```

Mandatory SQLfiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/82b5dd/1/0).

Explanation: The `theB` view filters the Type B events from the table for each customer. It is the joined to the transaction table on customer ID acting as a selector to keep only the rows with a lower `TransSqq`.

This might be more efficient as the `EXISTS`, as depending on result set sizes and indices there is no need to run a subquery for every row, if the `JOIN`ed view can be kept in RAM over the duration of the query.

Comment: Yes, could be faster than a correlated subquery, especially when OP is talking about million records.

Answer (score 2):

One approach uses an `EXISTS` query.  The `EXISTS` clause below checks, for each record in your table, all other records having the same `CustID` value, to check if any earlier records exist where the type is `B`.  If not, then that record would get added to the result set.

```
SELECT *
FROM DATA d1
WHERE
    d1.Type = 'A' AND
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM DATA d2
                WHERE d1.CustID = d2.CustID AND d2.TranID < d1.TranID AND
                      d2.Type = 'B');
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: you are saying that I need to create the new tables? can't I do it on the original table itself

Comment: What are you asking me?  You asked for a query, and I gave you one.

Comment: I got confused by the table you were using, however I understood your output

Comment: @Hardikgupta This works on the table itself. Tim just assigned two different aliases (d1 and d2), so he can relate different records of the same table to each other. In principle this is what the other answers do as well, and it's basically a requirement to solve this with a single table.

Answer (score 0):

A possibility would be to self-join the table. The query below has the *alias* A for the rows of type A, and B for rows of type B (while still using the same actual table, DATA). By grouping on A, you can use the *aggregate function* `min(B.TransSeq)` to get the lowest sequence of B for that customer. This allows you to get all A's that are 'before' min(B).

I was going to propose an second solution with a join on a subselect, but that's basically what Eugen Rieck proposed, so I'll stick with this one and let you test which works best in your scenario. The general idea is the same.

I don't know if this is faster or slower than the other solutions. I think this query would definitely benefit from having a combined index on (CustId, Type) and/or (CustId, Type, TransId). And if so, it may be more efficient, because it first joins then groups (allowing better use of indexes), or it  may be less efficient, because it has to work with a larger intermediate dataset. So it depends on various factors, including the indexes you have, hardware configuration, and whether you will query this for a small set of customers or for the entire table.

```
select
  A.*
from 
  DATA A
  inner join DATA B on B.custid =  A.custID and B.Type = 'B'
where 
  A.Type = 'A'
  -- and A.CustId = 100 -- if you like to filter by customer
group by
  A.TranId
having
  A.TransSeq < min(B.TransSeq);
```